# Laravel - How to add data to session

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, session

Hi I would like to store the following selection in session and echo in an other xxxx.blade.php page. Whenever I select new one the previous selection needs to be dropped.

DashboardController.php

```
$this->data['companyNames'] = \DB::table('tb_users')->orderBy('company_name')->lists('company_name', 'id');
```

index.blade.php

```
<form action="impersonate" method="post">
{!! Form::select('id', $companyNames) !!}
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You shouldn't ever try to hijack another users session

Comment: I know that but how ?

Comment: Do you really want to hijack an active user's session, or simply to log in as a different user?

Comment: My application needs to display only user generated content. So I need to log in as other user simply and post the task. The task row also have the `username` field. So with the following query the table will return only the user generated content.                                                                           `return "  WHERE username = '".Auth::user()->username."' ";`

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do to switch users it to login a different one:

```
Auth::login($user);
```

This is it made very simply:

Create a form with inputs:

```
<form action="/impersonate" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <select name="user_id">
      <option value="1">User 1</option>
      <option value="2">User 2</option>
      <option value="3">User 3</option>
      <option value="4">User 4</option>
    </select>

    <your submit button>
</form>
```

And a route to login your user:

```
Route::post('impersonate', function() {
    $user = User::find(request()->get('user_id'));

    Auth::login($user_id);

    return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I use it with a selectbox in html ?

Comment: Controller.php `$this->data['firstNames'] = \DB::table('tb_users')->orderBy('first_name')->lists('first_name', 'id');` index.blade.php `{!! Form::select('first_name', $firstNames) !!}`

Comment: Could you please revise your html code in accordance with this

Comment: Is this Laravel 4? `Form::select()` Is not Laravel 5, this was dropped a long ago. But you basically have to do what you already did.

Comment: It is Laravel 5.1 By the way the Route to login block gives syntax error. Could you please double check.

Comment: What route to login? The one I wrote is `impersonate`, but this is just an example, unless you show us all of your code, we cannot write it all, you have to think and write your code according to what you have.

Comment: try `<input type="submit" ...>`

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: Now button is working well. But I still can not switch the session between users.

Comment: Fixed a little problem: `return Redirect::to('/');`